# PyOpenGL-Demo sample code -- exiting app doesn't work

Tags: opengl, pygame

I am using the cube.py sample from PyOpenGL-Demo, and there is this snippet there to handle the app exit when user presses the Esc key:

```
def keyboard(key, x, y):
    if key == chr(27):
        import sys
        sys.exit(0)
```

There are two issue, one is pretty easy to fix (replace chr(27) by b'\x1b') but the sys.exit(0) call does not seem to fully close the app and clean up -- the window is still visible for example and the Python that was launched is still running.

I tried importing pygame and using pygame.quit() but that did not fix it... any ideas appreciated.

thanks